# Upper bound for the diameter of a prime constellation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

An admissible prime $k$-tuple with smallest possible diameter $d$ is known as a prime constellation.

What is the best known upper bound for $d$ as a function of $k$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is an "admissible prime $k$-tuple"?

Comment: @DanielFischer It is a $k$-tuple $a_1,\cdots,a_k$, witht the property that $n+a_1,\cdots n+a_k$ can be simultaneously prime and that there may be infinite many $n$ doing the job. $[0,1]$ is not admissible because clearly only $[2,3]$ is possible.

Comment: It is conjectured that for every admissible $k$-tuple, infinite many $n$ are possible.

Comment: @Sylvain Julien Do you want a bound for all $k$ or just for special $k's$ ?

Comment: A bound for all large enough $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is tabulated at [oeis](http://oeis.org/A008407). Some information from that site, where it's called $a(n)$:

Charles Greathouse IV says, $a(n) \gg n \log \log n$; in particular, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N$ such that $a(n) > (e^{\gamma} - \epsilon) n \log \log n$ for all $n > N$. Probably $N$ can be chosen as 1; the actual rate of growth is larger. Can a larger growth rate be established? Perhaps $a(n) \sim n \log n$.

Zhi-Wei Sun writes, Conjecture: (i) The sequence $a(n)^{1/n}$ ($n=3,4,\dots$) is strictly decreasing (to the limit 1). (ii) We have $0 < a(n)/n - H_n < (\gamma + 2)/(\log n)$ for all $n > 4$, where $H_n$ denotes the harmonic number $1+1/2+1/3+\cdots+1/n$, and $\gamma$ refers to the Euler constant $0.5772\dots$ [The second inequality has been verified for $n = 5, 6, \dots, 5000$.]

There are some references and some links, as well.